# Return IQueryable avoid returning ICollection

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm writing a mvc4 service that returns some data. How can i avoid returning ICollection from tables.
It will produce an unnecessary overload. In these example i just like to get `UserId` and `Username` avoid `UserInfos`.

Table

```
[Table("UserProfile")]
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UserInfo> UserInfos { get; set; }
}
```

MVC4 API

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Authorize(Roles = "administrator")]
    public IQueryable GetUsers()
    {
        var items = _uow.Users.DbSet.Where(x => x.Username == "FirstUser");
        return items;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using EF, Lazy loading mode (default setting true) should be off (in db context `Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;`). This will help prevent the UserInfo get loaded unless you ask explicitly using Include()

You should not return a IQueryable for reason such as to avoid UserInfo get loaded.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i can not add any tables like these _uow.Users.UserInfos.Add(new UserInfo()) without Lazy Loading. Why should i not return IQueryable ? By using DbSet i automatically load all stuff ?

Comment: I don't think there will be any problem adding table under lazy loading (I have not tried, so I could be wrong) - if there is a problem, what error message does it produce?

About IQueryable - sorry I wasn't thinking straight. By the look you are creating a web api which is good to combine IQueryable with OData.